# Problems with Dev Force Navigation Properties after multiple cache restores / imports

Tags: c#, silverlight, devforce

We've run into a very odd problem in our app where a navigation property on our entity ends up getting 'confused' in that it doesn't think there is an entity on the other end, when in fact there is.  The navigation property is a one-to-one navigation and I know we've had other problems with one-to-one properties in the past so maybe we've just hit an odd edge case bug?

In trying to reproduce the problem in the simplest possible way, I've found that I can reproduce it by doing an entityManager.CacheStateManager.RestoreCacheState(someCacheState) twice in a row.  Doing it twice causes the problem but doing it once doesn't.  In our app, we are restoring a cache state and that seems related to the problem.  I don't think we are restoring it twice but maybe we are?  Either way, it seems like it should be fine to do this?

Also, in our real app, I can reproduce the problem by doing an ImportEntities on a list of two entities (the two entities participating in the one-to-one relationship) **twice** .  In that case, I don't have to do the odd thing of restoring the same cache state twice to reproduce the problem - I just Import twice.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce the double-import in a clean solution.

Here is some sample code the demonstrates the expected behavior and shows the actual behavior:

```
private static void TestMultipleImports()
{
    //Any database with a one-to-one should work.  I'm using Adventure Works here but I've modified 
    //    it to have a one-to-one relationship.  For each Contact there are 0 or 1 Contact Details
    //    (they both have ContactID as the Primary Key)
    var mainEm = new AdventureWorksEntities();

    //Add a Contact and a Contact Detail with the same SID
    var contact = new Contact {ContactID = 1};
    var detail = new ContactDetail {ContactID = 1};

    mainEm.AttachEntity(contact);
    mainEm.AttachEntity(detail);

    //DevForce correctly matched up the entities so navigating from Contact to Detail or 
    //  from Detail to Contact works as expected
    Assert.AreSame(detail, contact.ContactDetail);
    Assert.AreSame(contact, detail.Contact);

    //In another entity manager, add the same Contact and Details
    var altEm = new AdventureWorksEntities();
    altEm.AttachEntity(new ContactDetail {ContactID = 1});
    altEm.AttachEntity(new Contact {ContactID = 1});

    //Use our helper method to import everything from our alternate EM into the main one
    ImportAll(altEm, mainEm);

    //Verify the navigations are still working
    Assert.AreSame(contact, detail.Contact);
    Assert.AreSame(detail, contact.ContactDetail);

    //Now do a similar import except we'll import into the dummy EM before importing into the main EM.  
    //  This 'double import' seems to cause the problem.  It would also break if we imported twice into 
    //  main EM.
    var dummy = new EntityManager();
    ImportAll(altEm, dummy, mainEm, mainEm);

    //Verify once more.  This one will pass ...
    Assert.AreSame(contact, detail.Contact);

    //...but this will fail.  The Contact Detail is in the Entity Manager and it can navigate to its related
    //   Contact...but for some reason, the Contact can't navigate to the Detail any longer.  Instead of 
    //   being the expected Contact Detail entity, it is a Null Entity
    Assert.AreSame(detail, contact.ContactDetail);
}

//Perhaps a bit of an odd way to copy entities between entity managers but it seems like this should be a 
//   reasonable thing to do
private static void ImportAll(EntityManager source, params EntityManager[] destinations)
{
    var ecs1 = source.CacheStateManager.GetCacheState();

    foreach (var destination in destinations)
    {
        destination.CacheStateManager.RestoreCacheState(ecs1, RestoreStrategy.Normal);
    }
}
```

We are running the latest (as of this writing) version of Dev Force 2012: 7.2.3.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember whether you're using DF 2010 or 2012.

Comment: Oops, I should have included that info. I've updated the question but we are on DF2012 - 7.2.3.

Comment: I'm unable to repro this with the Employee-SalesPerson 1:1 relation from AW2000, and see the correct behavior with both RestoreCacheState and ImportEntities.  Possibly the problem is in how the relationship is defined in your model.  Do you want to post (or send me) the EDMX for the Contact-ContactDetail entities?  Also, have you set the CloningFns.CloningMethod?

Comment: In our real app, we use the DCS CloningMethod.  But in my simple repro, I'm just using the default.  I've zipped up my sample solution (including the EDMX, etc.) - you can get it [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=32815104925768350206)

Comment: Thanks for the repro.  I'm still looking at this and don't have an answer for you yet.  I'll let you know when I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem here turned out to be an issue with how DevForce works with what it calls "unresolved parent" entities in a 1:1 relationship.  The multiple imports / mutating EntityCacheState issue was mostly a red herring but did expose the problem.

This has been fixed in version 7.2.4.

Comment: I can verify this.  Upgrading to 7.2.4 has fixed our problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have a fix for this, but if possible we'd like to get you the beta bits to be sure it fixes the problem in your application.  Let me know, and I'll zip up the packages for our ftp site.

The problem is that the EntityCacheState will actually mutate with each use, which can cause some weird edge conditions.

In your test case, you may notice good results with either of the following:

- if you create a new ECS within the foreach loop in ImportAll
- if you attach the altEm entities in the same order as is done in mainEm

I know the problem in your real app is somewhat different than the test case, but you might be able to tweak your code a bit as a workaround until 7.2.4 is released.

Comment: The problem is pretty easy to reproduce in our real app so I'd love to test out a beta version and let you know how it goes!  Thanks for the suggested workarounds.  That is very helpful.

Comment: Zip is named DF7.2.4.zip on our ftp site.  If you need the URL, PM me.

Comment: I got the update, thanks. It fixes the problem in my simple sample application but unfortunately, it doesn't fix the problem in our real app! :-(  I can try further reproducing the problem but I'm not sure how successful I'll be.  In our real app, I don't think we are using the ECS twice...we get it from the server as part of an RPC call and restore it once (I think).  Did there happen to be any other potential problems with restoring ECS?

Comment: Maybe something is going on with serialization of the ECS to the client followed by a restore.  I can try playing around with that.

Comment: I've tried all sorts of variations with retrieving an ECS from an RPC method and restoring/importing, but can't repro the error.  Unfortunately, the code for both entity merge (used in restore and import) and navigation properties is quite complex, so I can't really point my finger at any one spot which looks suspect.  If you want to send me relevant snippets from your real app I can try further.

Comment: I think I've found a way to reproduce it even with the latest patch version you gave me.  Can I email it to you?  Should I use your email at ideablade.com?

Comment: Sure.  Either to me or the support address.